# conjugate prior for my model parameter

Tags: bayesian, inference, gamma-distribution, conjugate-prior, variational-bayes

This question is related to the another thread that I posted: [Help with Variational Bayes on a weighted linear regression model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177706/help-with-variational-bayes-on-a-weighted-linear-regression-model)

To reiterate, I have the model as follows:

$$
y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(T(x_i; \beta), \frac{\sigma^2}{w_i} {\textbf{I}}) \\
\beta \sim \mathcal{N} (\beta_{0}, \Sigma_{0}) \\
w_i \sim \mathcal{G} (a, b) \\
$$

The full joint model can be written as:

$$
p(\beta, w, y |x) = \prod_{i=1}^{N} \bigg[p(y_i|x_i, w_i, H) \  p(w_i)\bigg] \ p(\beta)
$$

I suspect that using the Gamma distribution as a prior distribution for the weights $w_i$ is not opportunistic in the conjugate setting as I am unable to find the variational updates which allow the posterior distribution over $w_i$ being written in an analytical form as I am trying in that post.

So, my question is what distribution should I use for the prior on $w_i$ so that the posterior distribution after applying mean field and variational bayes inference comes out in some analytical form.

[EDIT]: The post @Xi'an pointed out deals with the so called g-prior but that example again does not try and estimate the weights of the regression problem in a Bayesian setting as far as I can tell.

Comment: Typically weights are known rather than estimated while $\sigma^2$ is estimated.

Comment: In my case, I am trying to estimate the weights.

Comment: @Xi'an So should the prior on the weights parameter by modelled by this g-prior? I will try and work it out. However, in my case, the prior is on the weights of the regression.

Comment: Right, I did not read carefully enough so retracted my vote.

Comment: What is the form of $T(x,\beta)$?

Comment: No harm done. Nice to know about this "g-prior". In any case, any suggestion/possible direction to pursue would be appreciated!

Comment: $T(x, \beta)$ is some generic transformation applied to $x$ and parameterised by $\beta$. Could be anything like a simple rigid transformation (rotation and scaling) or more complex non-linear ones.